# Cheapest way to transport PC from UK to Spain (Malaga)

Tags: united-kingdom, spain

I've recently moved to Malaga for a job at Oracle. I'm planning on being here for 2 years.

In doing so I've left a lot of my life behind in London.

I have a car which if I sold to a dealer, I'd be taking a massive loss on. And my PC which I built in 2012 which is slowly just growing more and more outdated.

My PC is in a huge Cosmos II case and weighs about 30/35kg in total. What would people suggest is the cheapest way of bringing it here alongside my 2 monitors?

Comment: Put your computer in your car, drive the car to Malaga (maybe via a ferry to Spain), then keep + re-register the car in Spain?

Answer (score 2):

Having a car is actually an advantage. If you would need to rent a van or otherwise procure one just to move, it could be too expensive but since you already have a vehicle, you can just pack your stuff in it and drive to Spain (surely you have got a few other things than your PC you had like to keep…). That's the way I moved between various EU countries and it always worked quite nicely.

There is usually some paperwork and, in your case, possibly some right-hand drive/left-hand drive issues but importing a car from within the EU is typically not that complicated. If you owned it for some time and import it as part of a move, it should also be tax-free. So that would take care of the what-to-do-with-the-car issue at the same time!

Alternatively, if you are certain that you will go back to the UK in two years (and not stay in Spain or move somewhere far away), you might also drive back with your car for your next holiday and park it somewhere with relatives or something (do beware that after you become a resident in Spain, you are probably not allowed to drive a UK-registered car there anymore).

Comment: You can drive a UK-registered car in Spain even if you're a Spanish resident. However, if you keep the car in Spain for more than 6 months then you have to import it. A good option may be to use it for the move and then drive back to the UK for Christmas and leave it with family. I don't know how easy it is to import right-hand-drive cars, but in general the pain points are translating all the documentation and paying a tax based on what Tráfico's tables of values say your car is worth.

Answer (score 1):

We were moving a lot of stuff from Poland, also screens and the computer, and we used courier services. It was worth it since if you pack the stuff correctly there is no way they can destroy it, it is quite fast and cheap. We transferred a lot of stuff this way. It was the cheapest way from Poland, I believe UK has it similar when it comes to prices cause the couriers are worldwide brands.[image]